# forestplot: How to define xticks when xlog=TRUE

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I would need to make three forestplots with the same x-axis and xlog=TRUE. However, when I set xticks, the image is squeezed to the left (including the largest defined tick value). Is there any way to adjust xticks, when xlog=TRUE?

If I just use 'clip' to define a longer x-axis, but do not set xtick, then tick division is calculated based on the original x-axis, not the new one, resulting in a problematic ticks division.

I would appreciate any advice.

Here is a toy example:

```
base_data <- tibble(mean = c(1.2, 2.1, 1.05),
                lower = c(1.05, 1.8, 0.8),
                upper = c(1.5, 2.3, 1.2),
                study = c("test1", "test2", "test3"),
                cases = c(36, 15, 9),
                controls = c("60", "17", "11"),
                OR = c("1.2", "2.1", "0.98"))


base_data |>
forestplot(labeltext = c(study, cases, controls, OR),
                         graph.pos=2,
                         clip = c(0.8,4),
                         xticks = c(1,2,4), #With this line, whole figure is squeezed to the left 
                         xlog=TRUE) |>
fp_set_style(box = "darkblue",
             line = "darkblue") |>
fp_add_header(study = "Study",
              cases = "Cases",
              controls = "Controls",
              OR = "OR")
```

(In the end, I decided to do a grouped image. Though that too was problematic. It required a nasty hack: I needed to combine table values of the same group to a single cell that was identical within the group and then I needed to separate values by '\n'. And manually adjust font sizes in different columns. I wonder whether there would be easier ways to do that... But that would be a separate question.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue although it was working before.

By installing a previous version (2.0.1) of the package I no longer have the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, apparently with the latest version of the package there is a problem with the xticks option combined to xlog=TRUE.

To fix it, i put log(x) for each value in my xticks.

Based on your example, this is the result :

[image]

If you just replace `xticks=c(1,2,4)` by `xticks=c(log(1), log(2), log(4))` , problem will be fixed. Here is the code:

```
base_data <- tibble(mean = c(1.2, 2.1, 1.05),
                lower = c(1.05, 1.8, 0.8),
                upper = c(1.5, 2.3, 1.2),
                study = c("test1", "test2", "test3"),
                cases = c(36, 15, 9),
                controls = c("60", "17", "11"),
                OR = c("1.2", "2.1", "0.98"))


base_data |>
forestplot(labeltext = c(study, cases, controls, OR),
                         graph.pos=2,
                         clip = c(0.8,4),
                         xticks = c(log(1),log(2),log(4)), 
                         xlog=TRUE) |>
fp_set_style(box = "darkblue",
             line = "darkblue") |>
fp_add_header(study = "Study",
              cases = "Cases",
              controls = "Controls",
              OR = "OR")
```

Here is the result with the correction of xticks :

[image]

This not the best fix, but it works, hope it will help you even if this is 4 months late!